# Travel Lens to UK

Tags: lens, travel

My family and I are planning to visit UK in October. My agenda is;
1. Visit old architecture of Bath
2. Strafford upon Avon
3. Lake District
4. Pitlochry 
5. London

I will travel with Nikon D7100 and the lens available are Sigma 17-50 F2.8, Tokina 11-16 F2.8, Nikkor 35mm F1.8, Nikkor 300mm F4 AFS and Tamron 150-600 VC.

I love architecture, landscape and also bird ( + hopefully salmon leaping). Will I see lot of birds at those places?

Do I need to bring along all those lens. Please help me choose.

TQ

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will see lots of birds in Lake District.

And of course if you want to maximize flexibility and quality of your photos, you "need" all those lenses, as they all have significantly different strengths and weaknesses.

But if your goal is to minimize the bulk of your travel kit, then I'd say that you can get by with the Sigma for landscape and architecture, and either the Nikkor 300mm or the Tamron lens for wildlife. Which one depends on whether what's more important to you: dealing with low light situations (the Nikkor is better at that) or shooting far away / small subjects (600mm is 600mm...)

Answer (score 0):

That of course depends. If the main focus on the trip is photography I'd bring them all. If the trip is just to enjoy the experience and take a picture here and there I'd be content to bring just the 35mm or the 17-50.

Answer (score 0):

You will see a lot of birds in those places. Salmon leaping, I'm not so sure.

Out of all your lenses, I would pick the 300mm zoom for your bird photography and something with a wide angle like the 17-50, the latter will be your walk about lens and with your D7100 you can use the 1.3x crop mode to give a bit more zoom if required.

Remember to pack your shorts, umbrella, sun cream, winter coat and sunglasses.

Comment: IIRC you do get salmon climbing upstream at Pitlochry there's a whole tourist thing up there around it